# How do I command the Rascal Shell not to truncate my output if it's quite long

Tags: rascal

This seems like a pretty basic question to me, but I don't seem to be able to find the answer anywhere. I need to get the full output of a command in the Rascal shell, however, Rascal seems to truncate long outputs automatically. Is there any way to tell the shell to always show the full output for a given command.

Example:

```
rascal>calculateCodeDuplication("smallsql0.21_src")
list[list[loc]]: [
  [
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(1310,26,<34,0>,<34,26>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(1494,56,<43,1>,<43,57>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(1558,49,<46,1>,<48,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(1616,44,<51,1>,<53,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(1665,57,<55,1>,<57,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(1731,51,<59,1>,<61,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(1791,57,<63,1>,<66,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(1853,65,<68,1>,<71,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(1927,61,<74,1>,<77,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(1993,56,<79,1>,<82,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2055,50,<84,1>,<86,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2114,54,<88,1>,<90,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2177,42,<92,1>,<94,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2248,7,<96,24>,<96,31>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2225,136,<96,1>,<101,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2390,8,<103,24>,<103,32>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2367,153,<103,1>,<107,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2526,54,<109,1>,<111,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2586,51,<113,1>,<115,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2671,16,<118,27>,<118,43>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2645,78,<118,1>,<120,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2731,49,<123,1>,<125,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2789,48,<128,1>,<130,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2846,48,<133,1>,<135,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2902,46,<138,1>,<140,2>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(2955,72,<143,1>,<143,73>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(3118,19,<149,43>,<149,62>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(3041,227,<146,4>,<152,5>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(1340,1931,<36,0>,<153,1>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/NoFromResult.java|(0,3273,<1,0>,<153,3>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/ExpressionFunctionLog.java|(1305,26,<33,0>,<33,26>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/ExpressionFunctionLog.java|(1418,51,<38,4>,<38,55>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/ExpressionFunctionLog.java|(1477,123,<40,4>,<43,5>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/ExpressionFunctionLog.java|(1337,266,<36,0>,<44,1>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/database/ExpressionFunctionLog.java|(0,1603,<1,0>,<44,1>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/junit/TestDBMetaData.java|(1298,23,<33,0>,<33,23>),
    |java+compilationUnit:///src/smallsql/junit/TestDBMetaData.java|(1325,18,<35,...
```

(note that the console outputs cuts off in the middle of the line with `...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways. Here are the two I use most frequently:

1. use `iprintln` or `println` from the `IO` module. The former does indentation which is nice for complex outputs. example: `import IO; iprintln(calculateCodeDuplication("smallsql0.21_src"));` The nice thing about this is that in the terminal values of `loc` type are hyperlinks
2. open an editor for the value using the `util::ValueUI` module (only in Eclipse), for example: `import util::ValueUI; text(calculateCodeDuplication("smallsql0.21_src"));` This will pop up an editor with the indented output value (nice to search in using CTRL+F, but the `loc` is not a hyperlink. Would love to have a contribution in that direction :-))

Caveat for the first one is that scrolling up and down in the Eclipse terminal is very slow on Mac's, and not really fast on Windows either.

Comment: Do we have something like the `text` function in the current version of Rascal?

Comment: Yes, in vis::Basic and vis::Text you can find functions that will show the entire file in a webview

Comment: You can also pass a larger `lineLimit` parameter to iprintln and friends